# How can I convert string 2015-04-15T12:48:00+05:30 to Salesforce DateTime format?

Tags: datetime

How can I convert string 2015-04-15T12:48:00+05:30 to Salesforce DateTime format? And also adjust the Timezone to be set to GMT +05:30?

Comment: is +5:30 also part of the string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try JSON.deserialize:

```
dt = (Datetime)json.deserialize('"2015-04-15T12:40:00+05:30"', datetime.class);
```

Note the double quotes inside the single quotes to make the date string a valid JSON date. That function should deserialize ISO-8601 datetime strings.